# System.xml not found on windowsphone

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8.1, braintree, system.xml

I am trying to implement braintree in a windows phone 8.1 app and on

```
            Result<Customer> result = gateway.Customer.Create(request);
```

i get error

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
      HResult=-2147024894
      Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
      Source=Braintree-2.41.0
      FileName=System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

I have included system.xml in every variation I could

full code at [github](https://github.com/Tippr-app/WindowsPhoneNEW/blob/master/tipper%20WP/tipper%20WP/Account_Creation.cs)

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I work at Braintree. Your best bet is to [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The Braintree .Net library isn't for use on the phone but on the server. Putting it on the phone would allow the user to access your API keys, run transactions, etc.

While Braintree used to have a [Windows Phone library](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/deprecated/client-side-encryption/windows-phone) it has been deprecated. Instead, you might be able to use a webview with JavaScript. I suggest you contact Braintree.